# how to use write attribute in switchcase should be an integer

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i have a rails app with questions and answers and each answer has has a rating depending on certain parameters like the example 
note: i dont want in terms of stars i want from 1 to 10 so i can take a weighted average of all the fields later and perform calculations.
how to use write attribute to fetch data?
error: SystemStackError: stack level too deep

```
def set_price_rating
  # set_price = 5
  puts case price_today
  when 1..21 then
    "0".to_i
  when 22..29 then
    "5".to_i
  when 30..39 then
    "7".to_i
  when 40..49 then
    "8".to_i
  when 50..59 then
    "6".to_i
  else
    "0".to_i
  end
  write_attribute(:price_rating, set_price_rating)
  save
end
```

Comment: you can try jquery raty plugin , you just need to pass the count of starts and rest of the functionality handled by the plugin .for more information check this  https://github.com/wbotelhos/raty

Comment: @pradeep i dont want in terms of stars i want from 1 to 10 so i can take a weighted average of all the fields later.

Comment: I believe you are new to Ruby so don't worry I have shared the answer below. Please devote some time to study instead of direct implementation as it will help you in other things too. Enjoy and welcome to rails.

Comment: The reason why you are getting the `Stack level too deep error` is probably because you are calling the method recurringly.

Comment: I don't understand your example ..., `set_price_rating` is a method in the Answer model? `price_rating` and `price_today` are attributes of Answer model? What you want to do is " trying to update the  `price_rating` according to the case switch rule when `price_today` is given " ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try and customize the below related gems:

https://github.com/wazery/ratyrate

or please devote some time to understand the concept here:

https://www.sitepoint.com/ratyrate-add-rating-rails-app/

Comment: in no way this gem lets me set custom parameters like i mentioned in the code.

Comment: As I mentioned, you will hardly find the gem as per custom if else case. But it give you and idea of calculation and you can overide gem calculation function dear.

Comment: Why have you not create common helper and common function or even you can use callback function, all depend on your approach. Also remove hardcoded value from loop, it may be change later.

Comment: anytime you have issue so you can update answer here and I will write code and update for you. Complete code written is not possible.